# Error in min max optimization formulation using PYOMO

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, pyomo, minmax

I am formulating my objective function for a min-max problem as written below

```
obj_func = power[1, i] for i in range(1, time_slots + 1)
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=obj_func, sense=pyo.minimize)
```

but I get the following error

> File "C:\NMBU\TEMP/ipykernel_24484/3898218797.py", line 21
> obj_func = power[1, i] for i in range(1, time_slots + 1)   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

It also throws an error if I use the below code

```
obj_func = (power[1, i] for i in range(1, time_slots + 1))
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=obj_func, sense=pyo.minimize)
```

> ValueError: Generators are not allowed

If I use the below formulation it works fine but then I don't need to optimize for the sum, I just want to optimize it to get the lowest value of power[1,i]

```
obj_func = sum(power[1, i] for i in range(1, time_slots + 1))
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=obj_func, sense=pyo.minimize)
```

Any ideas how to make it work, since PYOMO does not work with min/max directly?

I have already modeled **power >= (power in batteries)**, as I cant directly use min/max in PYOMO.

Answer (score 1):

You are going about this the wrong way.  The max() and min() functions are non-linear and can't be used in standard linear programming.

If your goal is to minimize the smallest value in a collection of values, you will need to introduce an additional variable, call it `t`, generate a set of constraints to force this new variable to be larger than each of the collection's elements ( `t >= x[i] for each i` ) and then just use `t` as your objective function and minimize it.

Comment: Hi AirSquid, thanks for your comment. Yes I have done that already. The 'Power' objective has been modeled like you have suggested. However when I use power in the objective function, I get the errors mentioned above.

Comment: I have also updated the question now.