# how to code a parameter when it is calculated by an equation

Tags: pyomo

in my code Tij is a parameter and it should be calculated like what I am showing below. how can I code it?
Tij= [tn, tm-a] ∪ Tj

Should I write it in param section?
I mean, do I have to define it like
model.T=Param{model.i,model.j, within=PositiveReals}, the equation written above

??

Comment: max() and min() are non-linear and cannot be used.  You'll need to reformulate a bit.  This might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72201089/error-in-min-max-optimization-formulation-using-pyomo/72205951#72205951

Comment: I just called them max and min. they can be other indices. but generally how can i code this param? if it is like:  Tij= [tn, tm-a] ∪ Tj

Comment: It isn't clear how to proceed from your question.  A `parameter` in optimization is a fixed value, so calculate it before you start.  If it is a variable of some kind you are going to need to correct the math above which makes no sense and post some kind of effort in coding it into your question in order to get a quality response

Comment: yes, i am sure that it is a parameter . However, i do not know how to code this equation. could you please help me?

Comment: Edit your code and explain your "equation" and include example data.  Right now it is gibberish.  What is T?  What is j?  What is an interval union with a set???  What is `a`.  Include example data **and** a desired outcome to make it clear.